# Дизайн Django админки

Tags: python, django

Возможно ли изменить дизайн Django админки? Если это возможно, то как это сделать? Где взять её файлы html, css? [image: Данную страницу нужно изменить]

Answer (score 1):

1. можно скопировать все базовые стили и html шаблоны
   https://djangodoc.ru/3.1/howto/overriding-templates/
   https://vedmark.ru/?p=1752
2. можно воспользоваться готовыми темами
   https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/admin-styling/
3. можно настраивать админки конкретных моделей:
   то есть скрыть\показать поля, добавить фильтры, настроить поиск и т.д.
   https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Admin_site

---

На самом деле настройка админки достаточно обширная тема, и за одно сообщение её не раскроешь

*Надеюсь смог немного помочь или задать направление для поиска :-)*

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос очень широкий и можно его разбить на подвопросы. Короткий ответ, да, можно.

### Про стили

Чтобы не копаться в исходниках существует команда для сбора всех стилей в одном месте - `collectstatic`. Данная команда собирает все стили из проекта, в том числе и админские в папку, которая указана в `settings.py`, как `STATIC_ROOT`. Выполните команду и все стили будут доступны в одном месте

```
py manage.py collectstatic
```

### Про функционал и стили в том числе

Django хорошо задокументирован и основаня страница по [админке(en)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/) содержит всю информацию и ссылки на связные темы. Так же здесь можно найти не только кастомизацию моделей и отображений, но и подключение стилей через обычное определение в коде. То есть можно  просто подкллючить `css` файл.

[Здесь пример](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/javascript/) для кастомизации с помощью javascript